# Do counterattacks count against your total attacks per turn?

Tags: combat, anima-beyond-fantasy

As per title - If you achieve a counterattack result, does that counterattack require that you have attacks remaining, or just that you be *able* to attack/take active actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! In fact you need to declare the number of attacks you're making in your turn the moment you do so, with the corresponding penalties applied for doing so.

If you have lost your action as part of being hit, or not having declared enough attacks, no counter attack for you.

Comment: oh no, my worst enemy, *planning.*

Comment: You can master Selene martial art, and then you have unlimited counterattacks that don't need to be planned.

Comment: That's highly impossible for lore reasons, but I suppose it's a theoretically viable build.

Comment: You can gain extra attacks via ki techniques, and restore lost actions with Ki as well. There's also an Ar's magnus that I cant rememeber the name of that gives unlimited counter-attacks. If you're a tanky fighter type, you could consider declaring "Absorbing Hits". If you have creature DP available you can take unstoppable.